# Start long running process using subprocess module

Tags: python, process, subprocess, multiprocessing

I am trying to start a java process that is meant to take a long time, using python's `subprocess` module.

What I am actually doing is using the `multiprocessing` module to start a new Process, and using that process, use `subprocess` module to run `java -jar`.

This works fine, but when I start the new process, the java process replaces the python process running python `Process`. I would like `java` to run as a child process in a way that when the process that started a new `multiprocessing.Process` died, the process running `java` would die too.

Is this possible?

Thanks.

Edit: here's some code to clarify my question:

```
def run_task():
    pargs = ["java -jar app.jar"]
    p = Popen(pargs)
    p.communicate()[0]
    return p

while(True):
    a = a_blocking_call()

    process = Process(target=run_task)
    process.start()

    if not a:
        break
```

I want the process running `run_task` to be killed along with the process running `java` when the process executing the while loop reaches the `break` line. Is this possible?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood the question, but why do you need the `multiprocessing` module? You can start child processes with the `subprocess` functions alone.

Comment: I need to start the new process and then continue running the while loop to start new processes.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should show some code, it's not clear how you are using subprocess and multiprocessing together.

From the documentation it looks like subprocess should spawn and not replace your new Process-started process.  Are you sure that isn't happening ? A test case showing it doesn't would be good.

You may get some hints out of [Detach a subprocess started using python multiprocessing module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1757388/detach-a-subprocess-started-using-python-multiprocessing-module)