# Flask multiprocessing does not return the response until a process is finished

Tags: python, linux, nginx, flask, uwsgi

I have a flask app with the code block:

```
if flag1 and flag2 and flag3:

        logger.info("Creating new process")
        p = Process(
            target=some_function,
            args=(
                param1,
                param2,
                param3,
                param4,
                param5
            ),
            daemon=False
        )
        p.start()
        logger.info("Return Now")
        return "OK", 200
```

Now, some_function takes a while to finish and I want to return the response to the client while it continues to do its work.

I get to the point where it logs "Return Now" but it doesn't seem to return yet. It seems like it's waiting for the process to finish before sending the response.

I'm not an expert at linux or at python and flask but It works when I test it in a Windows machine using the normal flask run or python -m app commands.

As an additional information, I have it deployed in a linux server with uwsgi and it's executed with the command:

```
uwsgi --socket 127.0.0.1:9003 -w wsgi:app
```

Why could this be?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT: I've also tried setting daemon to True but still the same result. Python version is 3.6

EDIT: The application's process is handled by supervisord where it is executed by uwsgi and is behind nginx that is passed with uwsgi_pass, if it helps.

EDIT: Thought I might want to add, I think this could be something with Nginx. As pointed out in the comments, it's highly unlikely that this is the flask application. The thing on top now is Nginx.

The real problem I'm trying to solve is: I'm sending a request to AWS API Gateway, which triggers a Lambda function that then makes the request to the API in a Linux server behind Nginx. The flask application works fine, except when it spawns the process, the control seems to not return. This happens when I call the API in Lambda, Postman or a python script.

Comment: How do you see that it does not return? Are you using a debugger or is it that yu expect an action that does not happen. I doubt the program gets stuck at a `return` statement. It is more likely somewhere in the framework in such a case.

Comment: I made a script that tests it using requests. Let's say I have the script:
`r = requests.get("path.to.api")`
In the console where the flask app is running, I can see that the log "Return Now" properly logged but the console where I executed my test script still does not end. It only ends when the some_function finishes processing.

Comment: It could be because of uwsgi forking behavior. Search pre-forking in uwsgi. Moreover, not an answer to your question, but it seems to me that you need a long-running process with a queue. In your request you can put a message inside the queue and your long-running process will consume it. You start the process upon starting your application.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're looking to do is detach the Process you're creating - in that case I would recommend trying the double-fork approach from this answer.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/49123627/6410635